# TripleDES Decryption truncating last character

Tags: encryption, encryption-symmetric, tripledes

I have a .NET class that implements TripleDES encryption and decryption. The code is too much to post here. However, the problem is that while encryption is OK, decryption is inconsistent depending on the length of the original plaintext. I know that encryption is OK since other triple DES tools also give same value.

Specifically, the last character is being cut off from the resulting plain text if the Length of the original Plaintext was 8,16,24,32,40 etc i.e 8n.

The encryption mode is CBC
The key size is 24 chars(192bits)
The IV is 8 chars

Comment: We can't help you without seeing some code :)

Comment: Don't let C/C++ mangle your brain, you are talking about "bytes" or "octets", not chars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because the (un)padding algorithm is not correct.

(3)DES encrypts/decrypts blocks of 8 bytes. As not all texts are precisely 8 bytes, the last block must contain bytes that are not original from the plain text. Now the trick is to find out which one is the last character of the plain text. Sometimes the length of the plain text is known beforehand - then the padding characters can be anything really.

If the length of the plain text is not known then a deterministic padding algorithm must be used, e.g. PKCS5Padding. PKCS5Padding *always* performs padding, even if the plaintext is N * blocksize in bytes. The reason for this is simple: otherwise it doesn't know if the last byte is plain text or padding: `41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 08 08 08 08 08 08 08 08` would be 8 'A' characters, with 8 padding bytes.

It seems that either the unpadding algorithm is not well implemented, or that a non-deterministic padding algorithm is deployed.

Comment: If you don't know the plain text length before the encryption and the cipher text is sometimes the same length as the plain text, then you are probably in trouble. Note that sometimes the plain text itself contains the length in bytes (e.g. when encrypting an ASN.1 defined object using BER/DER encoding).

Comment: I changed the padding mode from Zeros to PKCS7(other options available are ANSIX923,ISO10126 and NONE) and the decryption seems to work right now.Do you have an explanation why the decryption would work right with PKCS7 and NOT ZEROs Padding mode?? And YES, the length of the Plain text is variable.

Comment: Yes, the zero's padding mode is normally not deterministic: it just fills up the last block with zero's. So when the unpadding removes bytes, it may just remove the last 00h valued byte of the plain text as well. This is "fun" if you consider the plain text to be null terminated. Zero padding should only be used when plain text length is known.